# Can I add multiple editors on one admin page in wordpress. I need this if any idea then please instruct me

Tags: wordpress, editor, custom-post-type

Hi all I want to use multiple wp-editor in my WordPress website in admin panel page using custom posts.

When I try, it works but one thing isn't working which is media upload.

I need media upload to work properly, thanks.

Comment: What did you try for having multiple wp-editor in admin panels using custom posts? Hard to answer without knowing that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds like you need an editing group.  Check this out: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/editor-with-group-editing-capability

Comment: I think mutahir has problems with the WYSIWYG editor, not with users having editor privileges

Comment: Hi all , thanks for reply. Basically my requirements are using wp-editors more than one , If I use every thing works fine. But the prob is with media upload. when I want to upload an image to editor. the image to some where else means I want to upload it in one editor and it goes to another editor that is the main problem. I did't a lot research but couldn't find an answer. Then last hope is you people. Thanks All.

Comment: On one page I want more then one editor and it should work fine. that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php 
            $id1 = 'first_editor';
            $first = 'first';
            wp_editor($first, 'editor-'. wp_create_nonce($name) . wp_create_nonce($id1) .'', $settings = array('textarea_name' => 'first'));  

$id2 = 's_editor';
$second = 'second';
wp_editor($second, 'editor-'. wp_create_nonce($name) . wp_create_nonce($id2) .'', $settings = array('textarea_name' => 'second'));  
?>
```